# If my app uses AD B2C does it require Apple Sign-In?

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, apple-sign-in

Apple have changed their [store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122019b) to include Sign-In For Apple:

> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option.

If my app uses Azure ActiveDirectory B2C and allows social logins via this service (e.g. Facebook, Google) then am I required to support Sign-In For Apple? I know this is possible (see [Use Azure Active Directory B2C to enable ‘Sign in with Apple’ in your apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Azure-AD-Mailbag-Use-Azure-Active-Directory-B2C-to-enable-Sign/ba-p/566489) but I don't know if my app will be blocked from releasing until I do.

The user can just create an account on AD B2C. Apple also say:

> Sign in with Apple is not required if:
>
> - Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems.

But does this include a sign-in system that supports third-party social logins?

Comment: I guess it depends on "exclusively" - does the user have an option other than a social login?

Comment: Yes, they can create an account on AD B2C without it. See my update.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately Apple's language isn't very clear. If you *exclusively* use social then you must support sign in with Apple. If you *exclusively* use your own log in you don't need sign in with Apple. It doesn't say what happens if you dont use either method exclusively. You can either submit and see what happens, or support sign in with Apple; this is probably the best approach. Users like it when you give them easy options and support privacy

Comment: That's why I asked the question - I was hoping someone had already submitted.

Answer (score 0):

From https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Azure-AD-Mailbag-Use-Azure-Active-Directory-B2C-to-enable-Sign/ba-p/566489

> Using Sign in with Apple will be soon be required for all apps in the
>   Apple App Store which support third-party sign-in. This is indicated
>   at the very bottom of Apple’s recent update to its App Store review
>   guidelines. This requirement will be enforced once the service is out
>   of beta and commercially available.
>
> This new policy means that **if you implement any third-party or social
>   login** (like Facebook, LinkedIn, or Twitter) in your iOS or Mac apps,
>   those apps will also need to **include Sign in with Apple as an option**.
>   By using Azure AD B2C to enable social login in your applications, you
>   can be ready for this requirement when it becomes mandatory later this
>   year.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question - they're saying you can solve the requirement by using Azure AD B2C but don't say what happens if you're already using it.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. They weren't explicit in saying what happens in this scenario. My best guess is that since it's not being enforced yet, you're probably OK to submit it before then and have it pass certification without having Sign in with Apple. Then I think the app will probably be fine until the first time you need to update it after they start enforcing the requirement, and then it will be blocked from passing certification at that time. I doubt they would take the step and risk angering customers by removing an app from the store after the enforcement date if it doesn't comply.

Comment: @parsley72 Did you manage to get the app approved without "signin with apple"?
We need to use Azure AD for authentication and it doesn't make sense to us to include "signin with apple"